# How to turn column of number into a list of strings?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I don't know why I cant figure this out. But I have a column of numbers that I would like to turn into a list of strings. I should of mention this when i initially posted this but this isn't a DataFrame or did it come from a file this is a result of a some code, sorry wasn't trying to waste anybody's time, I just didn't want to add a bunch of clutter. This is exactly how it prints out.

Here is my column of numbers.

```
3,1,3
3,1,3
3,1,3
3,3,3
3,1,1
```

And I would like them to look like this.

```
['3,1,3', '3,1,3', '3,1,3', '3,3,3', '3,1,1']
```

I'm trying to find a way that is not dependent on how many numbers are in each row or how many sets of numbers are in the column.

Thanks, really appreciate it.

Comment: Is this column of numbers a file?

Comment: Is this a file? What does it have to do with pandas?

Comment: Just numbers, I don't know I like the efficiency of pandas.

Comment: The fact it is numbers is irrelevant, you have a list(essentially of strings) and you want to append each line to an array.  See Emisor's answer.

Comment: is it a string? is it a file?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you start with a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 1, 3], [3, 1, 3], [3, 1, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 1, 1]])

df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.values), axis=1).values.tolist()
```

Looks like:

```
['3,1,3', '3,1,3', '3,1,3', '3,3,3', '3,1,1']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
    l = []
    with open("file.asd", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            l.append(line)
    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn your dataframe in to strings, use the `astype` function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 1, 3], [3, 1, 3], [3, 1, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 1, 1]])
df = df.astype('str')
```

Then manipulating your columns becomes easy, you can for instance create a new column:

```
In [29]:

df['temp'] = df[0] + ',' + df[1] + ',' + df[2]
df
Out[29]:
0   1   2   temp
0   3   1   3   3,1,3
1   3   1   3   3,1,3
2   3   1   3   3,1,3
3   3   3   3   3,3,3
4   3   1   1   3,1,1
```

And then compact it into a list:

```
In [30]:

list(df['temp'])
Out[30]:
['3,1,3', '3,1,3', '3,1,3', '3,3,3', '3,1,1']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Done in Jupyter notebook
# add three quotes on each side of your column. 
# The advantage to dataframe is the minimal number of operations for 
# reformatting your column of numbers or column of text strings into 
# a single string

a = """3,1,3
3,1,3
3,1,3
3,3,3
3,1,1"""


b = f'"{a}"'
print('String created with triple quotes:')
print(b)

c = a.split('\n')
print ("Use split() function on the string. Split on newline character:")
print(c)

print ("Use splitlines() function on the string:")
print(a.splitlines())
```